# How to use Eigen::Map on matrix of matrices?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I need to write a wrapper for using an existing third-party library within a C/C++ DLL.
The library is heavily relying on [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org) for matrix manipulations and I want to reuse that code without modifying it.

I'd like to use Eigen::Map to convert between the Eigen matrices of the library and the standard C-style arrays in my DLL interface. For the inputs I have this working, but the output is a 4x1 matrix of 3x4 matrices and I can' figure out how to map that the proper way.

This minimum example code is working:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

void matrix_test(double* in, double* out)
{

    // Map input array to 3x3 matrix (and match layout)
    Map<Matrix<double, 3, 3>, 0, Stride<1, 3>> matrix_in(in, 3, 3);

    // -- library would be called here --
    // (taking matrix_in and filling matrix_out)

    Matrix<Matrix<double, 3, 4>, 4, 1> matrix_out;
    
    // Map 4x1 matrix of 3x3 matrices to output array
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Map<Matrix<double, 3, 4, RowMajor>>((out + i * (3 * 4)), 3, 4) = matrix_out(i);
    }

}
```

I'd like to get rid of the `for()`-loop. I would assume there is a way in Eigen to use Map for the matrix-of-matrices, but it seems I can't figure out how - I only get a long list of compiler errors (but then this C++ template-stuff is quite new to me)

Does anybody have a hint or an example how to achieve this with Eigen::Map?

Thank you
Felix

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the return type of the function?  I'm not following a 4x1 matrix of 3x4 matrices.  For example I could interpret this as a `Matrix<Matrix<double, 3, 4>, 4, 1>` which I don't believe is possible.

Comment: `Matrix<Matrix<double, 3, 4>, 4, 1> matrix_out;` fails to compile on my machine and on godbolt using Eigen 3.4.0. (https://www.godbolt.org/z/K8YcPGTa8)  Are you using a custom version of Eigen?